# Improving a poorly used theme of a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, presentations, technical-environment

I have completed a technical presentation, but I have tried many times to customized to improve the appearance of the PaloAlto.

Very Very...Long Conf Title cannot be accommodated in the side bar, also the frame title,  is spilling over.

Below is the sample title page and slide :

```
    \documentclass{beamer}[10]
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage[danish]{babel}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
    \usepackage{graphics,epsfig, subfigure}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage{srcltx}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    %\usepackage{enumitem}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{pgfplotstable}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{mathtools}


    \usepackage{tikz}

    \newcounter{boxes}

    \mode<presentation>
    \usetheme[numbers,totalnumber,compress,sidebarshades]{PaloAlto}

    %  \usecolortheme[named=kugreen]{structure}
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%  \usecolortheme{}
      \useinnertheme{circles}
      \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
      \setbeamercovered{transparent}
      \setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

    %\logo{\includegraphics[width=1.2cm]{Capture}}
    %\useoutertheme{infolines} 
    \title{Very Very Very Long  Conf Title}
    \author{Very Long Name}
    \institute{Institute}
    \date{28 January 2014}



    \begin{document}
    \frame
    {
    \frametitle{Insert some long Conference Name, it is so long that it spills over to the next line along with the date of conference.}
    \titlepage \vspace{-0.5cm}
    }

    \section{Conclusion}
    \frame
    {
    \frametitle{Thank you}
    \begin{itemize}
       \item How do I make the conclusion title more prominent?
    \end{itemize}
    }
    \end{document}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Thanks. Incidentally, is there a reason why you first load the `PaloAlto` theme and then the `AnnArbor` theme?

Comment: @Mico,  
I wanted to experiment with different styles, only to genuinely improve the outlook of my final presentation. I did not know(want to know) which is a better theme for an academic presentation

Answer (score 3):

(This answer got revised thoroughly after the OP clarified his/her objectives and affirmed a focus on working with the `beamer` theme "PaloAlto".)

- Don't use `\frametitle{<some very long title>}` on the title page. In fact, it's probably not necessary to provide a `\frametitle` instruction for the title page at all. Instead, work with `\title`, as noted in the following bullet point.
- The `\title` macro can take both a "short form" and a "long form" argument; the former should be encased in square brackets, the latter in curly braces. E.g.,

  ```
  \title[Abbreviated title]{Full, long, and very elaborate title}
  ```

  If the `PaloAlto` theme is used, the abbreviated title rather than the full title will be shown in the left-hand-side title bar.

Comment: @AgrimRaghav - Done. I've also deleted the my comments in the comment chain above, and I suggest you do the same.